# When should datasource be instantiated in connection pooling

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, connection-pooling

So, I was exploring on how to use connection pooling on java web application. I looked at some tutorials and I am wondering when should I do the context lookup.
Something like this

```
initContext = new InitialContext();
dataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/mysql");
```

Should it be everytime I get a connection, or should it be a one time thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously initialize connection pool one time only, you can do lookup any time required.

Note: The init-context is not creating connection pool